# react- cleaning autocomplete generates an error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I have a form created with `material-ui`, I have a textfield that uses autocomplete which is filled with a `useEffect` that is responsible for bringing the data from the API to load the AUTOCOMPLETE.

The data is not saved.

Code

```
  const defaultProps={
    options:location.name,
    getOptionLabel: option =>  option.label + "-" + option.phone,
  };


  <Autocomplete
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        {...defaultProps}
        id="city"
        autoComplete                   
        onChange={(event, newVal)=>onChange({target:{name:"name",value: newVal.label }}
          )}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params}   label="Country"  margin="normal" variant="outlined" inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
          }}/>
        )}
```

What is causing that behavior?

Comment: What code runs when you "click clear"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your problem in on the following line:

`onChange={(event, newVal)=>onTagsChange({target:{name:"label",value: newVal.label }}`

It may be related to newValue being `null` after clearing. You could add a protection such as:

`value: newVal || newVal.label`

Since it is not clear to me how you are using the resulting selection my suggested protection may not be appropriate.

You may also want to take a look at their "controlled" example in the documentation (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground) in which they use the `value` attribute to control the `AutoComplete`:

```js
<Autocomplete
 {...defaultProps}
 id="controlled-demo"
 value={value}
 onChange={(event, newValue) => {
  setValue(newValue);
 }}
 renderInput={params => (
  <TextField {...params} label="controlled" margin="normal" fullWidth />
 )}
/>
```